# What happened to the community wiki checkbox?

Tags: discussion

As far as I remember, there used to be a checkbox at the bottom of the question form to mark it as community wiki (CW). I don't see it anymore. I assume this functionality changed. How does it work now?

I ask because I posted a new question that I would have marked as CW:
[What words can I use to indicate how hungry I am?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/what-words-can-i-use-to-indicate-how-hungry-i-am/22741#22741)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[It was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action), because it was “causing confusion and pain”. To get a question marked as Community Wiki, flag it for moderator attention with an appropriate comment.